# iOs 8, Core Motion and Cycling activity

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios8, core-motion

Finally for supported devices and in iOs8 only, CMMotionActivity has another tracking capability which is "cycling".

However no matter how hard I try, there is no way to make the device, which is an iPhone 5S, to detect cycling. Here's my code:

```
CMMotionActivityManager *manager = [[CMMotionActivityManager alloc]init];
[manager startActivityUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMMotionActivity *activity) {
    if(activity.running){
        _txtMoveType.text = @"running";
    }
    if(activity.walking){
        _txtMoveType.text = @"walking";
    }
    if(activity.automotive){
        _txtMoveType.text = @"driving";
    }
    if(activity.stationary){
        _txtMoveType.text = @"standing";
    }
    if(activity.cycling){
        _txtMoveType.text = @"going on bike";
        UIAlertView*alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Bike!" message:@"you are riding a bike, aren't you?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yay!" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show ];
    }
}];
```

I am not sure why activity manager doesn't detect cycling, as it does detect fairly well any kind of activity supported.

I've tried also to query past activity with

```
- (void)startActivityUpdatesToQueue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue
                    withHandler:(CMMotionActivityHandler)handler;
```

But the results don't change. In fact it is possible to check these activity also in the new HealthKit app, and there's no trace of biking.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found this on the "What's new in iOs8" document (no trace of it on the reference)

> Core Motion Framework
>   Core Motion provides two new classes (CMAltimeter and CMAltitudeData) which allow you to access the barometer on the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus. On these two devices, you can also use a CMMotionActivity object to determine whether the user is on a bicycle.
>   "

It seems there is no static method to test if the device is supported:

```
[CMPedometer isStepCountingAvailable]//returns YES on Iphone 5S
[CMPedometer isDistanceAvailable]//returns YES on Iphone 5S
[CMPedometer isFloorCountingAvailable]//returns NO on Iphone 5S
```

Anyway, it seems not possible with the use of CMMotionActivityManager alone.

Comment: Cycling detection isn't working in Health app.  See this threadhttps://discussions.apple.com/thread/6548678?tstart=0 (I'm having the same issue).  If I had to guess, I'd say the API isn't fully baked yet.